# Simple problem about solutions to the differential equation $u'(z)=(u(z))^{2}+z$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE: $u'(z)=[u(z)]^{2}+z$ where $u:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is meromorphic.

Question: let $u$ be an arbitrary solution to the above equation, prove that $u(z)$ must have infinitely many poles.

The problem is not too hard if $u(x)$ is just $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. For $x>>0$ then $u$ just blow up very fast, faster than $\tan$, so there is a pole at arbitrarily large positive $x$ further than any sufficiently large $x$, so there must be infinite number of poles.

But I'm not sure how to transfer this argument into complex realm. It seems like such a simple problem though, so maybe I missed something obvious.

Comment: There's a difference between "infinitely many poles" and "a pole at infinity".

Comment: @WhatsUp: of course I'm talking about infinitely many poles.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Riccati equation. Use the form $u=-\frac{v'}v$ to get the linear equation
$$
v''(z)+zv(z)=0
$$
This now is an Airy equation, and it is known, for instance via the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem, that this function has infinitely many roots on the positive real axis, distributed similar to $x_k=(3k\pi/2)^{2/3}$, $k\in \Bbb N$.

> Any root of $v$ is a pole of $u$.

The equation is considered over the complex plane to get a continuation of a solution beyond the first pole. Any real solution has no continuation past poles, after it diverges, the end of the maximal domain is reached. The linear equation for $v$ is uniquely solvable over any disk of finite radius.